# Issue with incremental encrpyption on specific Android device/OS

Tags: java, android, kotlin, encryption, cryptography

I am using incremental encrpyption, in combination with Android KeyStore provider.

```
val cipher = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION)
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getSecretKey())

val chunks = textToEncrypt.chunked(CHUNK_SIZE)
val encryptedChunks: MutableList<ByteArray?> = mutableListOf()

chunks.forEachIndexed { index, chunk ->
     if (index == chunks.size - 1) {
            encryptedChunks.add(cipher.doFinal(chunk.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
     } else {
            encryptedChunks.add(cipher.update(chunk.toByteArray(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)))
     }
}

val result = encryptedChunks.filterNotNull().reduce { acc, item -> acc.plus(item) }
```

These are the constants I am using:

```
const val TRANSFORMATION = "AES/GCM/NoPadding"
const val CHUNK_SIZE = 32768 // 32KiB
```

Now, this code has been heavily tested on more than 30 different devices, and never had any problem whatsoever, except with one phone (Xperia XA with Android 7.0). For this phone, if the input (`textToEncrypt`) is small enough that everything can be encrypted in a single chunk then it is fine, but if it is bigger (normally around 100KiB), so that it needs more chunks, then it will not be able to encrypt the data. This is what I get:

```
Caused by javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException
   at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:491)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2056)

Caused by android.security.KeyStoreException: Memory allocation failed
   at android.security.KeyStore.getKeyStoreException(KeyStore.java:685)
   at android.security.keystore.KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.update(KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java:132)
   at android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineUpdate(AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java:338)
   at javax.crypto.Cipher.update(Cipher.java:1683)
```

**NOTE**: Only for this device the `cipher.update()` returns null with `ENCRYPT_MODE` , that's why in my code I allow to return null, and then discard them for forming the encrypted data.
This means that `cipher.doFinal` is supposed to return in one go the whole encrypted data.

**EDIT:** So apparently only for this phone the chunk size is not fine: it cannot be 32Kb, but 8Kb works fine

Comment: have you tried increasing the CHUNK_SIZE?

Comment: Hi @Mike No, I didn't, but I would like to try first a deterministic approach. Like discovering the real cause, and then apply the fix. Because yes I can try all different chunk sizes, but I will never have the guarantee it will work on every device.

Comment: It says memory allocation failed, so the natural thing to do is to *decrease* the chunk size. Try reducing it to 32. And the "real cause" may simply be a buggy device or even a buggy model.

Comment: Yes, it might be a buggy device. The current chunk is  already pretty small: 32Kb. I am not sure makes sense to have a smaller one. I just don't want throw away all the tests that we did so far, changing the chunk size.

Comment: For what it is worth, the code looks fine to me too. If you go for smaller chunks: the native block size of AES is 128 bits (16 bytes) maybe try that? (Notice you can get 1 to 4 bytes in UTF-8 for a single char!)

Comment: @JohannesB  So it turns out that yes, for that specific phone, with that specific version (7.0) the chunk was too big. I can't believe this!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your findings, this could be a useful to others. Great commitment on testing on your part!

Comment: Did you test with other phones under Android 7.0?

Comment: Yes @Olivier but only emulator. It shouldn't be different from real device though.

Comment: But you said that you needed to buy the phone to reproduce it. So maybe all phones with that version of Android have the issue.

Comment: No, I mean: the feature was in alpha and a user with Sony Xperia XA with Android 7.0 had the issue. Since we didn't have that phone, we tried to reproduce it on other devices (emulated) with the same API level (Android 7.0), but no problem there. That's why we bought that specific phone, and we could understand the source of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Expanding on Olivier's answer. He's determined that the exception is thrown by `mMainDataStreamer.update()`. If you look at [`AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/nougat-release/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java#285) class you will see that `mMainDataStreamer` is an instance of [KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/nougat-release/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/KeyStoreCryptoOperationChunkedStreamer.java) class. Here's an interesting part:

```
// Binder buffer is about 1MB, but it's shared between all active transactions of the process.
// Thus, it's safer to use a much smaller upper bound.
private static final int DEFAULT_MAX_CHUNK_SIZE = 64 * 1024;
```

In our case, this default max chunk size is used. `DEFAULT_MAX_CHUNK_SIZE` puts an upper limit on the chunk size. If you pass bigger chunks to the `cipher.update()` method they will be cut into chunks of `DEFAULT_MAX_CHUNK_SIZE`.  As you can see, even developers of Android didn't new the precise safe chunk size and had to guess themselves (unsuccessfully, in your case).

However, notice that [Binder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder) buffer is used to pass these chunks to the encryption process and results back from it. And it's size is only about 1MB.

Maybe there is an unusually small Binder buffer on this particular device? You can try to look into it by using that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25666064/3249257

On future devices, you can use:

```
IBinder.getSuggestedMaxIpcSizeBytes()
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/IBinder#getSuggestedMaxIpcSizeBytes()

Answer (score 2):

I've spent some time analyzing the issue. I couldn't find the real cause, but at least I have found some elements, so here they are.

### Multi-part processing

First, you say that you use a chunk size of 32Kb, but it's not really true. You split the string in chunks of 32Kc (32768 **characters**), then you convert each chunk to a byte array. Since the UTF-8 representation of a char can range from 1 to 4 bytes, your byte array will generally be *larger* than 32Kb (unless you have only ASCII chars).

You should first convert the string to a byte array, *then* split it into 32Kb chunks. Only that will guarantee the size of the buffer that you pass to the crypto API.

### Client-side error

Now, about the stacktrace you get. Contrary to what it seems at first glance, the error doesn't occur in `doFinal()` but in `update()`. When you call `update()`, the call is delegated to [`AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineUpdate()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/nougat-release/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java#320). The interesting part is:

```
try {
    flushAAD();
    output = mMainDataStreamer.update(input, inputOffset, inputLen);
} catch (KeyStoreException e) {
    mCachedException = e;
    return null;
}
```

It calls `mMainDataStreamer.update()`, which fails and throws a `KeyStoreException` with code [`KM_ERROR_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_FAILED`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/nougat-release/core/java/android/security/keymaster/KeymasterDefs.java#242). But the exception is caught, stored in `mCachedException`, and `null` is returned. That's why you get `null` when you call `update()`.

When you call `doFinal()`, it calls [`AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.engineDoFinal()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/nougat-release/keystore/java/android/security/keystore/AndroidKeyStoreCipherSpiBase.java#487):

```
protected final byte[] engineDoFinal(byte[] input, int inputOffset, int inputLen)
        throws IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    if (mCachedException != null) {
        throw (IllegalBlockSizeException)
            new IllegalBlockSizeException().initCause(mCachedException);
    }
```

The method sees that there is a cached exception and throws it (wrapped in an `IllegalBlockSizeException`, which is totally unrelated to the real issue).

### Keystore error

Now, the real issue. The actual work of encryption/decryption is performed by the Keystore service, which is a separate process written in C++. The relevant part for AES is in [aes_operation.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/keymaster/+/refs/heads/nougat-release/aes_operation.cpp).

There is a number of `KM_ERROR_MEMORY_ALLOCATION_FAILED` errors returned in that file. As its name suggests, the code means that a memory allocation has failed. So it seems that, for some reason, the Keystore was unable to allocate a buffer. It's hard to understand why.

### Conclusion

Since the real cause is mysterious, I would suggest keeping a small buffer size *and* changing the splitting procedure as described at the beginning.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your investigation! :)  The size of the chunk is exactly as the size of my input, even if there is the conversion, because the input contains only ASCII. But even if it wasn't, my 32Kb was just arbitrary, because couldn't find the maximum value that the `update()` method supports or at least the recommended one.